# Are there any Design Patterns for Service Layer in MVC Application?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am designing a service layer for a web application where there are overlapping services. While there are several ways to solve such problems,  I would like to hear design patterns recommended by the experts in such scenarios.

I am designing a taxi app for some practice. I have two main entities here car and a driver. So, I have two separate controllers lets call them DriverController and CarController and two interfaces in the service layer lets Call CarService and DriverService and there default impls which connect to DAO layer. All of these together are good to facilitate basic CREATE/DELETE/UPDATE/MODIFY on Car and Driver entity.

No, let's say I want my application to return the list of cars owned by a particular driver

For example: {"drivername":"alex","cars":[{"carname":....etc....}]}

I would design an endpoint like GET  /drivers/{drivername}/cars

which would trigger the driver controller.

Now, in the service layer, I am confused where should I write a business logic for this task. Should I add another method to the Driver Interface or should I have another interface extending this? Should I add another method like getCarsForDriver in the DefaultDriverServiceImpl or should I extend this DefaultDriverServiceImpl and add a method to it?

Here there is a one-to-many relationship between a driver and a car. Are there any design patterns/approaches to address such relationships?

Comment: The question is very broad and as it is written there is no right or wrong answer. One assumption to challenge is the idea that a direct relationship must exist between `Car` and `Driver`. An alternative to consider is a third API, `CarAndDriver`, whose sole purpose is to manage that relationship so `Car` and `Driver` remain decoupled from each other.

Comment: Can you share any examples about what have you tried? For example, if you just try to implement method `getCarsForDriver` in DriverService, does it work? I mean the question is broad and here it doesn't matter so much which service you use. I would say that try and see if it feel "right" way. For example, if you want get user cars, do you prefer calling `driverService.getCarsForDriver()` or `carService.getCarsForDriver(driverId)`.